jsstore indexeddb not allowing multiple ! values in regex expression
When we are firing the below query on jsstore DB the multiple '!' values are not executed; ideally the result was expected that it should return data of all countries whose name not brazil & mexico. Any way to achieve this?
select({
from: 'Customers',
where: {
country: {
regex: /!mexico|!brazil/i
}
}
})
Multiple not conditions to be added in where clause like notin
